# How to insert delimiter in a string with kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I have a mac string:

> mac=7A2918D5434F

And I need to convert to this:

> mac=7A:29:18:D5:43:4F

How can I do that in kotlin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are sure that your initial string is correct you can do something like:

```
"7A2918D5434F".chunked(2).joinToString(":")
```

`chunked(2)` splits the string in chunks of size 2 (can be used for any `Iterable`).
`jointToString(":")` takes a list, joins the elements to string using `:` as delimiter